# How to find out which anchor tag is being clicked and get the id in CanJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs, canjs

I have dynamically generated anchor tag in ejs.

```
<div style="position: absolute" class="template-box">
    <!--<a  href="#!template-detail" class="b2bdist">B2B Distributor</a>-->
    <% for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { %>
    <a href="#!template-detail" id="<%= this[i][0].id%>"> <%= this[i][1].name %> </a> <br>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

The **href** is same for every anchor tag. Now when any anchor will be clicked it will come into below code:

```
case "template-detail":
           var template_id;
           // here i want to get the the anchors id which is clicked
           $("#template-detail").show();
           break;
```

Here to notice that my href is same and in any click i will go to same controller in canJs. When the href is clicked it will come to the routercontroller and routercontroller will call this function in my mainAppController. so my **this** is changed to now mainAppController. So i can't use **this.id** something.

**Edit:** I used below code in my js but didn't fire. It goes to the case using href directly because of the router controller i am using.

```
   $('a').click(function(){
                console.log(this.id);
            })
```

***How to get the id of the anchor tag which is clicked ??***

**Edit:** *sorry to everyone. I need it in CanJs.*

Comment: use `this` context in click event

Comment: Post your full js code for anchor clicks.

Comment: I am not handling anchor click just using href for every tag in other js file in canJs. I want to handle it there? is it possible??

Comment: can you provide a fiddle/plunkr/codepen example to test with?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class attribute in all `<a>`,
example HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="myclass" id="id1">Text one</a>
<a href="#" class="myclass" id="id2">Text two</a>
<a href="#" class="myclass" id="id3">Text three</a>
```

example JS:

```
$('a.myclass').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have and event object? if so you can access `event.target.id`

Answer (score 0):

Have attribute "name" in the anchor tag and have click handler based on that

```
$('a[name="uniqueid"]').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);
});

 <a href="#" name="uniqueid" id="id1">Text one</a>
<a href="#" name="uniqueid" id="id2">Text two</a>
<a href="#" name="uniqueid" id="id3">Text three</a>
```

Comment: If you want to validate based on click, have the href as "#" and have this click handler. In the handler, route it to your href value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Jquery. Solution is;

```js
    $(function(){
//document ready
        $('a').click(function(){
          alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="firstone">First Link</a>
<a href="#" id="secondone">Second Link</a>
<a href="#" id="thirdone">Third Link</a>
```

Comment: The thing is that i am calling a controller using the href in another js file. Actually that is firing. Not this click event in my js file.. href is firing because of canJs routercontroller have in my project

Comment: Did you wrap your code with document ready ? Sometimes it is required, depends on your plugins and project.